# Why is the buffer continue to be filled even when the CODEC is not receiving an input?

Tags: stm32, hal-library, hal

I am currently using the HAL function

```
HAL_I2S_Receive(I2S_HandleTypeDef * hi2s, uint16_t * pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
```

in order to collect an input signal (currently being tested with a function generator 440 Hz sine wave). However, we noticed a couple of things:

1. The data being stored in every index of our uint16_t * pData buffer is radically different. The values do not follow a trend. We expected to see an increase and a decrease in the values as it reads sine wave, however, we just see random values ranging from 0 - (2^16).
2. When we stop the signal from the function generator the buffer continues to get filled up. This behavior continues even after unplugging the function generator line from the input to the codec.

MCU   - STM32F446RE
CODEC - PCM3060

Why would the values in the buffer continue to be filled up, and why are they not showing a trend that would represent reading a sine wave?

Comment: I2s doesn’t know if there is a valid input or not - it sends/receives samples continuously. As to why your samples don’t make sense - could be many things. Is the codec configured correctly? What tests have you done to verify this?

Comment: Also do you mean to be using HAL_I2S_Receive? Transmit sends data, it doesn't read/acquire.

Comment: @TypeIA Yes, sorry. I corrected my post.

Comment: @Kartman We have configured the CODEC using I2C, as far as the configuration goes, we have made the CODEC the master, therefore it uses its own independent clock. We also got it out of low power mode. All these changes made it possible to work.

As far as testing goes, we have done the proper testing to check that the codec works (checking the clocks are running at the correct freq. and running a feedback loop from the output to the input to check it works right)

Comment: @dcm why do you think the codec would know that your function generator was turned off? If there's no signal, it should return a bunch of 0s to say that the input is 0.

Comment: @user253751 no doubt, the function that handles I2S does not understand whether theres and input stream coming in or not, it just runs indefinitely, however the values seeing the live expression console suggest the opposite, we are actually seeing values ranging from 0 - 2^16 even when the function generator is turned off.

Comment: @dcm I think I2S is signed, so you should check whether it's just fluctuating between 0 and -1 or so due to noise; if you want it unsigned then to convert signed to unsigned you can just xor with 0x8000

Comment: @user253751 Our codec is currently biased so that no negative values are passed.

Comment: @dcm well 2^16-1 is a negative value and you just said you saw it...